# MariaDB & MySQL very slow on Windows 10

Tags: performance, mariadb, wamp, settings

I'm using WAMP on a Windows 10 (i5,ssd) machine and noticed the websites are quite slow. Much slower than on my old Windows 7 (i3,hd) PC.

When I loop a simple script with a calculation:
Win10: 0.4 sec
Win7: 9.5 sec

But when I add database queries in a loop, it's the opposite:
Win10: 147 sec
Win7: 15 sec

The script I use insert a simple hash in a table "test":

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `testvalue` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The PHP testscript:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$time_start = microtime(true);

$insertTotal = 100000;

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "speedtest";
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$db->query("TRUNCATE test");

for($i=0;$i<$insertTotal;$i++)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO test VALUES(null,'".md5(time().rand(0,999999999))."')");
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
echo 'Total exec time: '.$execution_time.' sec.';
```

There are quite a few topics about this, so I will sum up all I already did:

1. Change servername from localhost into 127.0.0.1
2. Apache: disable CGI
3. PHP: disable Xdebug
4. Disabled firewall
5. Disabled virusscanner
6. Data dir on different Harddisk

raised buffers a lot in my.ini:

```
key_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 4M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
```

So what else I'm missing here?

Some additional info: when executing the script, the SSD is having 0% load and the CPU has about a 30% load.

**Update:**

- Reinstalled Wamp 3.2.3.
  Tested it with MySql 5.7.31, 8.0.21 And MariaDB 10.4.10, 10.4.13, 10.5.5.
  There is a difference of a few seconds here and there, but still slow.
- Also I changed the script to use $db->multi_query($sql) see if this works. The result for inserting 10.000 rows is 0.13sec on the old computer and 8.5 seconds on the new one.
- Just to be sure it's not the SSD or something I wrote a same testscript only using SQlite3 this time and insert 1.000.000 rows in just 7 seconds, so it is only MySQL and MariaDB only.
- Installed VMWare windows 7 on the new PC with Wamp 2.5. Interesting, the execution time is about the same, also slow.

Comment: Please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE test;` (for both PCs)

Comment: @EugenRieck: ok I did, same for both PCs

Comment: Just ran your code. On I7(series -1) HDD, WAMPServer against MariaDB and MySQL and got a fairly consistant 6.4 seconds for both.With no changes to my.ini

Comment: And with XDEBUG still configured

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for testing. This proves my DB is indeed way to slow. I'm about 23 times slower. Although you have a faster processor, this seems to be way too much a difference....

Comment: 1. Check if insert or connecting is slow by measuring connect and by measuring insert (instead of measuring entire script).
2. Make sure autocommit is set to off, e.g. by sending BEGIN before INSERT and COMMIT after insert.

Comment: Hi @GeorgRichter, measuring the connection gives me 0.02 sec, so that seems not be the problem. I tried the option you described, not familiar with it, it seems to speeds thing up but online like 40% or so. Still the gap is huge compared to my old PC. The reason I need the speed is that I need to insert millions of records for testing. I don't want to wait hours every time :).

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any OS Swap Space on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
Windows version is at  https://github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner  
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @WilsonHauck, this is gonne take some time to provide, as I'm also not familiar with all these points to be honest. Will come back to this later.

Comment: We are here to help you.

Answer (score 1):

***#update#***
There was actually a problem with my PC indeed. I fixed it at last (https://superuser.com/questions/1584203/windows-10-very-slow-how-to-find-the-cause) and now the test script runs 34 times faster. So also the better script that use multi value insert is way faster. The whole WAMP runs many times faster now. Glad this is solved.
***#update#***

After spending way to much hours on this issue I went on working on my actual import script and suddenly realize I have been barking up on the wrong tree all along. I have been trying to fix a problem that was not actually a problem.

Sure, it's not correct I have a write speed of 500 seperate queries per second when the old PC can do 50.000 or so, but I should never gonne use seperate queries after all. I was so focused on this problem, that I did not realize the performance issue was not effecting  everything else persé that MySQL and MariaDB could do.

So Rick James answer was actually right thinking.

Sorry guys for wasting your time. Thank you for helping me! I have been working days on problems before and fix them, but never work on a problem so long that was not a real problem at all!

To give an example, I modified the test script a bit. This can insert 200 million rows in about 14 minutes:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$time_start = microtime(true);

$insertTotal = 200000000;

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "speedtest";
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$db->query("TRUNCATE test");

$counter = 0;
$sql = array();
for($i=0;$i<$insertTotal;$i++)
{
    $sql[] = "(null,'".md5(time().rand(0,999999999))."')";
    if($counter == 5000)
    {
        $sql = implode(",",$sql);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO test VALUES ".$sql.";");
        $counter = 0;
        $sql = array();
    }
    $counter++;
}
$sql = implode(",",$sql);
$db->query("INSERT INTO test VALUES ".$sql.";");    

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
echo 'Total exec time: '.$execution_time.' sec.';
```

Answer (score 0):

- Move from MyISAM to InnoDB
- Batch 100 rows in a single `INSERT`; it will run about 10 times as fast.
- Depending on the amount of spare RAM and which Engine you are using, some tuning should be done.
- Multi-query should never be used.
- `autocommit` is irrelevant to MyISAM.
- 100K `INSERTs` in a single transaction has other problems.  Either do the batching, above, or put only 100 inserts in a transaction.  (Going above 100 in either case is "diminishing returns".)

Comment: When moving to InnoDB, the execution time doubles.
Of course there are a lot of ways to improve the insertion as you mention. My importing script is indeed much more sophisticated than the test script above. The test script was to show how much slower the DB is on the new machine. That is the problem I'm trying to figure out. 
For example, I can insert 100 million records when using SQlite3 in about 14 minutes, but with MariaDB or MySQL this takes me days. Due to other reasons, I prefer not SQlite, this was only testing.